# Does 'Digressing others' make sense?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, phrases, expressions

One of my friends said the other day:
'Digressing others is a part of my job'

Does this phrase make sense?

Comment: Have you checked to see if any major dictionaries state that 'digress' can be used transitively? I've just checked in 4, and they all say that (but this is general reference, so I'll let you make sure for yourself).

Answer (score 1):

Not a *lot* of sense.  As Edwin suggests, *digress* is an intransitive verb, it does not take a direct object.  Your friend probably meant *sidetrack*, which means to cause to someone or something (typically a conversation or argument) to digress.  "Sidetracking others is a part of my job.

(Of course, had you at the time gone into a long disquisition about intransitivity and the importance of proper grammar until your friend got bored and attempted to return to the subject at hand, you could have have laughed, "Hah, I digressed *you*!" and blown his mind.)

Comment: I'm usually tempted to downvote answers to questions obviously GR, but +1 here for the 'sidetrack' suggestion. Marvellous. Reminds me of the time Poirot, fed up with staying with Hastings at a French golfing hotel, said something like 'I shall return to England, and let you continue to work on your disability'.